# Split a list on a separator - keeping the separator in the group

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a weird data structure that is returned to me by an external service I have no control over.

The data is essentially a list of dictionaries, but chopped up in a strange way: it is returned as a list of dictionaries, where each of these dictionaries has a *single* key. Taking multiple elements from this list yields all the keys in the dictionary.

In code:

```
[ {'id': 1}, {'a': a}, {'b': b}, {'c': c},
  {'id': 2}, {'a': a}, {'b': b}, {'c': c},
  {'id': 3}, {'a': a}, {'b': b}, {'c': c},
  ...
]
```

Every dictionary that I want to reconstruct starts with the `id` dictionary. After I find the `id` key, I need to take all the values from the list until I find another `id`.

My current solution is:

```
def split_groups(data, key='id'):

    groups = []
    for e in data:
        if key in e:  # begin new group
            groups.append(list())
        groups[-1].append(e)

    return groups
```

which works, but it's ugly. I know about `itertools.groupby`: however, I can't really understand how to use it.

The result of this line:

```
[(k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(data, lambda d: d.get('id') is not None)]
```

is:

```
[(True, [{'id': 1}]),
 (False, [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]),
 (True, [{'id': 2}]),
 (False, [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]),
 (True, [{'id': 3}]),
 (False, [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}])]
```

As you can see the `id` dictionary ends up in a different group than the following values.

What am I doing wrong?

---

After Sumukh Barve's answer, I guess that groupby just isn't the right tool for my job. My current code will do for production; just for fun, I rewrote it like this:

```
def split_groups(data, key='id'):

    if not data:
        return []

    predicate = lambda d: key not in d
    head, tail = data[0], data[1:]

    group = [[head] + list(takewhile(predicate, tail))]
    rest = list(dropwhile(predicate, tail))

    group.extend(split_groups(rest, key))
    return group
```

which is a much less efficient, much less readable, much more OCD-appealing form.

Thanks everyone for your help!

---

Just in case that somebody one day stumbles into my same problem, I am attaching [the full solution](https://gist.github.com/Ippo343/2e2d943d6dea9dd9593a) with some example data.

Comment: You can't use `groupby` for this - that would only work if all of the dictionaries within a group had the same key for `id`, it won't do *"all of the things are in this group until I say otherwise"*. Just stick with your current code - I would consider a `defaultdict(list)` mapping `{group_id: list_of_dicts_in_group, ...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):**

> It (`itertools.groupby`) generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes . . .

In that sense, `itertools.groupby` is similar to `str.split`; the difference being that the split sequence is also included in the output.

```
"1,2,3".split(",") ==> ["1", "2", "3"]
"1,2,3".splitLikeGroupBy(",") ==> ["1", ",", "2", ",", "3"]
```

**So, you aren't doing anything wrong.**

Also, I'd say that your solution is good.

**But, if you insist on using `itertools.groupby`, try this:**

```
a = [(k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(data, lambda d: d.get('id') is not None)];
[a[i][1] + a[i+1][1] for i in range(len(a)) if i % 2 == 0]
```

The first line comes straight from your code. The second is some simple processing.

**Suggestion:**

Instead of working with a list of list of single-element dictionaries, you may want to work with a list of multi-element dictionaries.

That is, instead of working with this:

```
[
    [{"id": "id1"}, {"a": "a1"}],
    [{"id": "id2"}, {"a": "a2"}], ...
]
```

You might want to work with this:

```
[
    {"id": "id1", "a": "a1"},
    {"id": "id2", "a": "a2"}, ...
]
```

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: Your suggestion unfortunately is not applicable as the dicts that follow the id might contain duplicate keys that I cannot merge using dict.update, so I need to isolate the group and process it before I can get a single dict out of it.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for considering the suggestion. Best.

Comment: I updated my question to add the full solution I am using, and also some example data. You will see that the structure I am getting is quite convoluted :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is not a trivial task.
A solution in two lines :

```
ind=[i for i,d in enumerate(l) if 'id' in d]
slices=[l[a:b] for (a,b) in zip(ind,ind[1:]+[len(l)])]
```